# Speech-to-noise ratio in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11+

Tags: windows-7, microphone, dragon-naturally-speaking

The speech-to-noise ratio [was changed to Pass/Fail in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4353/~/unable-to-complete-the-audio-setup-wizard-(microphone-check)) in the Audio Setup Wizard (Microphone Check).

Dragon NaturallySpeaking 10:

[image]

Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11:

[image]

Is there still a way to see the speech-to-noise ratio in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to see the speech-to-noise ratio in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 11+.